# Mock private methods using FakeItEasy

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, fakeiteasy

I have achieved a solution to mock test the public virtual method using FakeItEasy Framework. Below I have a Test class with Private method and private method cannot be virtual. So please help me t mock the Private method using FakeItEasy Framework

**Class To be tested**

```
public class XYZ
{
    public static int nValue = 0;

    private  void AddInetegers()
    {
        int i = 3;

        int j = i * 100;
        int k = j * 30 / 100;

        Show(String.Format("Value Here {0}", k.ToString()));

        nValue = k;
    }

    public virtual void Show(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
[TestMethod]
   public void Test_Using_FakeItEasy()
    {

        var instance = A.Fake<XYZ>();

        A.CallTo(() => instance.Show("Hello"));

        //A.CallTo(() => instance.AddInetegers(3)).CallsBaseMethod();

        A.CallTo(instance).Where(x => x.Method.Name.Contains("AddInetegers")).MustHaveHappened();


        Assert.AreEqual(90, XYZ.nValue);
    }
```

**Error:**

> Result Message:    Test method PrjMSTest.Test.Test_Using_FakeItEasy
>   threw exception:  FakeItEasy.ExpectationException:
>
> Assertion failed for the following call:
>       Any call made to the fake object.
>         where x => x.Method.Name.Contains("AddInetegers")
>   Expected to find it at least once but no calls were made to the fake  object.

Comment: Simply - you cannot mock private methods (unless you are using commercial mocking frameworks). You never need to test private methods, because private methods will be always called through public methods - so testing public methods you will test private as well

Comment: FakeItEasy is commercial mocking frameworks??

Comment: you never need to mock private methods.

Comment: @andreasnico This question is related to Mocking Private Method,  Other question was for Partial Mocking.  only the thing is I have used same sample code. How it  can be duplicate?

Comment: @SujeetSingh did you solve this?

Comment: @FrancescoB. I achived using the  PrivateObject class, for reference you can go to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396996/how-can-i-use-privateobject-to-access-private-members-of-both-my-class-and-its-p

Comment: I reject this romanticized view of testing. There is nothing wrong with testing private methods. There is everything wrong with saying "you never need to mock private methods" or "Make it public if you need to test it". These are archaic nonsense views. I regularly unit test my private methods via reflection calls. You cannot chastise people for wanting to test more. And no there is nothing wrong with your architecture if you want to test a private method, that is a bunk claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they told you in the comments, you can't easily test private methods and, in the vast majority of cases, probably you shouldn't.
If, for some reason, you still want to test `AddInetegers()`, there's a "dirty" way to keep some kind of information hiding and to test your method.

First, you have to make `AddInetegers` internal; it won't be visible outside your assembly and you will be able to test it.

Then find the  Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file of the project to which your `XYZ` class belongs to; supposing your project is named `MyProject` and your test project is `MyProjectTests`, you can add

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

to the top of AssemblyInfo.cs and

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProjectTests")]
```

to the bottom. This will make your method testable. More info [here](https://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-using-internalsvisibleto-attribute-to-help-testing-non-public-methods/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358196/c-sharp-internal-access-modifier-when-doing-unit-testing).

---

Then there's an even dirtier way, i.e. keeping your method private; it's mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607491/5480409) or [here](https://akurniaga.wordpress.com/tag/unit-test-privateobject-visual-studio/) and relies on `PrivateObject`, which has been around since 2004 as per [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamesnewkirk/2004/06/07/testing-private-methodsmember-variables-should-you-or-shouldnt-you/) by James Newkirk himself

```
var CurrentInstance = new XYZ();
var PrivateObject= new PrivateObject(CurrentInstance);
PrivateObject.Invoke("AddInetegers");

Assert.AreEqual(90, XYZ.nValue);
```

---

Honestly, unless you're dealing with very complex legacy code, you might wanna leverage your design skills and think about why you want to test a private method and why its author decided to make it private.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401015/5480409) is very thorough about why you shouldn't test private methods and/or why those methods you want to test shouldn't be private.
But it also explains why you might need to do it:

1. When refactoring and/or adding tests to a legacy system that perhaps you still haven't had the time to get acquainted with

> sometimes it is simply safest to just test the private functionality

2. When someone gave you an unreasonable deadline

> You're in a rush, and have to do the fastest thing possible for here
>   and now. In the long run, you don't want to test private methods. But
>   I will say that it usually takes some time to refactor to address
>   design issues. And sometimes you have to ship in a week. That's okay:
>   do the quick and dirty and test the private methods using a groping
>   tool if that's what you think is the fastest and most reliable way to
>   get the job done. But understand that what you did was suboptimal in
>   the long run, and please consider coming back to it (or, if it was
>   forgotten about but you see it later, fix it).